# how to run click function after default behaviour of a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".mes_sel",function(){
        if($(".mes_sel:checked").length==0){
            alert("Checked");
        }
        else alert("Not Checked");
    });
});
</script></head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="mes_sel">
</body>
</html>
```

It is alerting checked when the textbox is unchecked because onclick is running before the checking of checkbox.How can i make the click event to run after checking/unchecking of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `change` for that:

```
$(function(){
    $(".mes_sel").on("change", function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Not Checked");
        }
    });
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MusFh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("body").on("click", ".mes_sel", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else alert("Not Checked");
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WCUh6/)**.

Comment: So help me in decide which is better yours or Anytrat

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a while back - I also found that different browsers handled this differently.  Chrome was the worst offender, if I remember correctly.

This isn't necessarily the best solution, but you could attach a custom attribute to each checkbox, say "isChecked", and then base your function off this attribute like so:

```
if ($("mes_sel").attr("isChecked") == "true") { ... }
```

Like I said, not the best solution as you will have to manually flip the "isChecked" attribute in order to stay consistent with the actual checked value of the checkbox, but it will work if nothing more elegant will work for you.

If you'd like an example of this , check out this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/GAP2j/

This turns regular radio buttons into "toggleable" radio buttons - I was forced to use this custom attribute method because of the different way browsers execute `onclick` events.