# Check if checkbox is NOT checked on click - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a checkbox just got unchecked, when a user clicks on it. The reason for this is because i want to do a validation when a user unchecks a checkbox. Because atleast one checkbox needs to be checked. So if he unchecks the last one, then it automatically checks itself again.

With jQuery i can easily find out wether it's checked or not:

```
$('#check1').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        alert('checked');
    else
        alert('unchecked');
});
```

But i actually only want to have an if statement that checks if a checkbox just got unchecked.

So i thought i could do that with the following code:

```
$('#check2').click(function() {
    if($(this).not(':checked'))
        alert('unchecked');
    else
        alert('checked');
});
```

But this will always show the 'unchecked' message. Not really what i was expecting...

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tVM5H/

So eventually i need something like:

```
$('#check2').click(function() {
    if($(this).not(':checked')) {
        // Got unchecked, so something!!!
    }
});
```

But obviously this doesn't work. I rather don't want to use the first example, because then i'd have an unnecessary 'else' statement when i only need one 'if' statement.

So first thing, is this a jQuery bug? Cause to me it's unexpected behaviour. And second, anyone any ides for a good alternative?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tVM5H/1/)

Answer (score 71):

The answer already posted will work. If you want to use the jQuery :not you can do this:

```
if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)'))
```

or

```
if ($(this).attr('checked') == false)
```

Comment: The first example in this answer seems the easiest to read out of all the options, so I vote for that.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery to check for checked? Really?

```
if(!this.checked) {
```

Don't use a bazooka to do a razor's job.

Comment: If using jQuery to find the element, it should read `$(this)[0].checked`

Comment: @HoldOffHunger It's part of the native input element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

If you are using jQuery then Chris has the correct syntax in the comment above yours.

Comment: @TheZ : Nice!  Yes, you are right, answer by Chris is good.  Suggestion: Add it to answer with credit?  Both OP and top answers lean towards $(selector).is('...'), which is a pure jQuery solution.  Only using `.checked` where they have `.is('checked')` will not work by itself.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#check1").click(function() {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            if (checked) {
                alert('checked');
            } else {
                alert('unchecked');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 if(jQuery('input[id=input_id]').is(':checked')){
  // Your Statment
 }else{
  // Your Statment
 }

 OR

 if(jQuery('input[name=input_name]').is(':checked')){
  // Your Statment
 }else{
  // Your Statment
 }

</script>
```

Code taken from here : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2015/10/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked-or.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out some of the answers to this question - I think it might apply to yours:

[how to run click function after default behaviour of a element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158874/how-to-run-click-function-after-default-behaviour-of-a-element/11159050#11159050)

I think you're running into an inconsistency in the browser implementation of the `onclick` function.  Some choose to toggle the checkbox before the event is fired and some after.

Comment: This is actually really important too.

Comment: And that's why jQuery to check for checked. Really. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Answer already posted .But We can use the jquery in  this way also

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DAfgj/1/)**

```
$(function(){
    $('#check1').click(function() {
        if($('#check1').attr('checked'))
            alert('checked');
        else
            alert('unchecked');
    });

    $('#check2').click(function() {
        if(!$('#check2').attr('checked'))
            alert('unchecked');
        else
            alert('checked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
if (typeof $(this).attr("checked") == "undefined" )

// To check if checkbox is checked
if( $(this).attr("checked")=="checked")
```

Comment: This could just be `this.checked`. The first line doesn't need `typeof` there (it will never raise a `ReferencError`). You should also be using `prop()` instead of `attr()`, which will return a boolean, making your second one also redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Below code also will work

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" /> Check1

$('#check1').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") == false)
    {
    alert("Unchecked");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Checked");
    }    
});
```

or

```
$('#check1').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)"))
   {
   alert("Unchecked");
   }    
});
```