# Call javascript function when specific radio become unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio inputs and I would like to call a JS function only in the case where the `id3` radio is selected and becomes unselected.

I searched, but I found only solutions, where only checked/unchecked status is checked:

```js
$("input:radio").change(function() {
  if ($("#id3").is(":checked")) {
    alert('checked');
  } else {
    alert('unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" id="id1" data-refresh="5" class="">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" id="id2" data-refresh="5" class="">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" id="id3" data-refresh="5" class="">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if checkbox is NOT checked on click - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159221/check-if-checkbox-is-not-checked-on-click-jquery)

Comment: Where is the code you given falling short? You could maybe reduce this by using the selector `$('input#id3').change(...)`

Comment: Your current code works as long as you include JQuery and wrap the code in `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep track of when you last clicked it, to see if you need to say that it was unselected.

### Plain JS

This is fairly simple to do in pure JavaScript. You can utilize the `data-*` attribute design to store the state of when an element was last checked.

```js
let targetEl = document.getElementById('id3');

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')).forEach(radioEl => {
  radioEl.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === targetEl.id && e.target.checked) {
      alert(e.target.id + ' - checked');
      e.target.setAttribute('data-waschecked', true);
    } else if (targetEl.getAttribute('data-waschecked') === 'true') {
      alert(targetEl.id + ' - unchecked');
      targetEl.setAttribute('data-waschecked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" id="id1" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" id="id2" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" id="id3" data-refresh="5">
```

### jQuery

This advanced solution allows you to monitor multiple radio buttons. It is written mostly in jQuery.

```js
const trackableIds = [ 'id1', 'id3' ];

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(e) {
  let $target = $(e.target),
      isTrackable = trackableIds.includes($target.attr('id'));
  if (isTrackable && $target.is(':checked')) {
    alert($target.attr('id') + ' - checked');
    $target.attr('data-waschecked', true);
  }
  trackableIds.filter(trackId => trackId !== $target.attr('id'))
    .forEach(trackId => {
      let $trackable = $('#' + trackId);
      if ($trackable.attr('data-waschecked') === 'true') {
        alert($trackable.attr('id') + ' - unchecked');
        $trackable.attr('data-waschecked', false);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" id="id1" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" id="id2" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" id="id3" data-refresh="5">
```

#### As a jQuery plugin

Nearly identical behavior to the jQuery above, but as a plugin. There are even custom callback function options for checking/unchecking.

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.trackRadio = function(ids, opts) {
    this.on('change', function(e) {
      let $target = $(e.target), isTrackable = ids.includes($target.attr('id'));
      if (isTrackable && $target.is(':checked')) {
        opts.onCheckFn($target);
        $target.attr('data-waschecked', true);
      }
      ids.filter(trackId => trackId !== $target.attr('id')).forEach(trackId => {
        let $trackable = $('#' + trackId);
        if ($trackable.attr('data-waschecked') === 'true') {
          opts.onCheckFn($trackable);
          $trackable.attr('data-waschecked', false);
        }
      });
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$('input[type="radio"]').trackRadio(['id1', 'id3'], {
  onCheckFn : function($radio) {
    alert($radio.attr('id') + ' - checked');
  },
  onUncheckFn : function($radio) {
    alert($radio.attr('id') + ' - unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" id="id1" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" id="id2" data-refresh="5">
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" id="id3" data-refresh="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add a watcher variable to find out whether you are deselecting the radio button.

```
var isChecked = false;
$("input:radio").change(function () {
  if ($("#id3").is(":checked")) {
        isChecked = true;
    } else {
      if (isChecked) {
        alert("Unchecked");
        isChecked = false;
      }

    }
});
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/LYYjLrv?editors=1010